# The tags [simulations] and [quantum-simulations] - should they be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

[quantum-simulation](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-simulation) has only one question and no description, but the question would fit with [simulation](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation) which has a description and many questions. Should [quantum-simulation](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-simulation) be marked a synonym of [simulation](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, these tags should be synonymized.

The tags seem to cover the exact same thing, and one is definitely more widely used and self-explanatory than the other.

Comment: But wouldn't "quantum simulation" and "classical simulation" be extremely different concepts, and wouldn't it make sense to have separate tags for either of them?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch perhaps but as it stands [tag:simulation] is used for quantum simulations.

Comment: What has been used for classical simulations?  Nothing?  In either case, I feel that synonimizing "simulation" with "quantum-simulation" is kind of symmetry breaking - I feel there should be tags for classical & quantum simulation, and people choose whatever is better (since they should be offered both when typing "simulation")

Comment: @NorbertSchuch would you mind posting an answer with that then? That would require some retagging, I think.

Comment: I agree that we should have tags for both: many existing questions don't fit very well with `quantum-simulation`. Maybe `quantum-simulation` and `classical-simulation`? I don't really like `classical-simulation` as a term in this context, but it could avoid endless mistagging

Answer (score 3):

I think we should have two different tags, one for *quantum simulation* in the sense of using a quantum system to simulate another one, and the other for the problem of simulating quantum systems with classical devices.

For example, [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/3899/55) and [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/3860/55) questions are about *simulation* but not about *quantum simulation*, while [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1478/55) and [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2074/55) are about *quantum simulation* (though the last one is more specifically about *hamiltonian simulation*).

However, I do agree that having [simulation](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation) and [quantum-simulation](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-simulation) would be source of endless confusion and mistagging.

Perhaps we could have [quantum-simulation](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-simulation) and [classical-simulation](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classical-simulation), and make `simulation` as synonym for `classical-simulation`?
The rationale about synonymizing `simulation` this way is that I would expect people not knowing the difference to be more likely asking about `classical-simulation`.